# JPA bulk insert if not exists

Tags: jpa, persistent

I have 3 entities - Player, Hand and PlayerHandStats. First two are regular tables, with ID as an PK. PlayerHandStats on the other hand has a composite PK (player_id, hand_id). Together they form some sort of a "package", that's why I am trying to persist them in one block. ParsedHand is just a class which bundles the entities - it contains 1 Hand, 2..10 Player and 2..10 PlayerHandStats. Below is my current naive approach, which doesn't really work.

```
public static void persist(ParsedHand parsedHand) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    em.persist(parsedHand.getHand());

    Collection<Player> players = parsedHand.getPlayers().values();
    for (Player player : players) {
        em.persist(player);
    }

    Collection<PlayerHandStats> stats = parsedHand.getStats().values();
    for (PlayerHandStats phs : stats) {
        em.persist(stats);
    }

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
}
```

Problem is, that a specific Player entity may already exists in the DB - in that case the whole process terminates. I would like to keep it going, not perform any merge or update upon the entity, but retrieve its' ID (since at application level it has no ID assigned).

Quick example (**NOTE**: columns NAME and POKER_SITE form an UNIQUE CONSTRAINT):

```
ID  |NAME        |POKER_SITE
----+------------+------------
0   |neverlimp92 |PokerStars
1   |player01    |PokerStars
```

Now, let's say I have a Player entity at application level with fields (null, 'neverlimp92', 'PokerStars'). Obviously, it will return java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException, and the whole process terminates. How can I avoid this? Should I override the hashCode() and equals() methods, and perform

```
for (Player player : playes) {
    if (!em.contains(player)) {
        em.persist(player);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if this is a smart thing to do, considering there may be potentially 10k's, even 100k's rows.

And also, if the entity does exists, what is the proper way of retrieving its ID and assigning it to the existing instance at the application level?

I have very little experience with JPA, and any kind of help, or pointing me in the right direction is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the players may be existing players, then for each player you need to query the database for the player with that name and site, if one exists use it, if it does not then persist it.

This depends on how likely it is that their is such a player.  If it is very unlikely, then you could just persist it, and if the commit fails, then retry with the second algorithm.

In general it would be better if your player had its id, then you would know if it is new or existing.